# rename multiple file add number to name using batch

Tags: shell, command-line, batch, batch-file

I have files in folder named `unix_aaa.txt` `unix_bbb.txt` `unix_ccc.txt` and so on.

How do I change all the files that start with `unix` to names like

```
001_unix_aaa.txt

002_unix_bbb.txt

003_unix_ccc.txt
```

Comment: is it batch or bash?

Comment: is it not the same 

i dont know both are fine i think > <

Comment: batch=>windows, bash=>linux.
The script answer would change **completely**.

Comment: ahhh it's batch :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a batch (windows) script that will do this

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set n=1
for %%a in (unix_*.txt) do (
if !n! lss 10 (
ren "%%a" "00!n!_%%a"
) else (
if !n! lss 100 (
ren "%%a" "0!n!_%%a"
) else (
if !n! geq 100 (
ren "%%a" "!n!_%%a"
)
)
)
set /a n+=1
)
```

Comment: can i ask more output came out as 001 - 010 then it is 010 instead of 011 how should i fix it or there is no way

Comment: What do you mean? I don't follow :)

Comment: :D meanthat 001_unix_aaa.txt until 009_unix_aaa.txt then at 010 it comeout like 0010_unix_aaa.txt it should be 010_unix_aaa.txt i'm try to explain as much as my english can >_<

Comment: Oh right, I get you now :D It should already do that, I made it check so it would go like 001 010 100 etc I will do some testing!

Comment: hey hey i got it now thank you becuase of i didnt type it all correct that why its error thank You  :D :D :D :D :D

Comment: Ah right, no worries.

Comment: Hey What does %%a stand for   
and 
!n!  it i want to know how to use it

Comment: `%%a` means the file that it is currently looping on, and `!n!` is the number that it appends on the file.

Answer (score 1):

This is for Bourne shells.

```
n=1; for f in unix*
do
    mv "$f" "`printf %03d $n`_$f"
    n=$((n+1))
done
```

Comment: it's not working i put in text document then change it .bat everyfile name stil be the same but thank you

i found the problem what is it printf in cmd command

Comment: just normal command line  

i dont know much about it

all i used to do is type in .txt file then change it .bat and run

Comment: @eathapeking what does `echo $0` say ?

Comment: nothing change :) here example of filename

unixinv_RSSPA_16Nov2012.csv

Comment: From 1st comment, looks like it's [tag:batch] & not [tag:bash]